# Как организовать многопоточность в этом примере?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Как организовать многопоточность в этом примере на Python

Подключенные модули:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import threading
```

```
iterar = input ('How many domains you want to check: ')
domainlist = []
try:
   iterar = int(iterar)
except ValueError:
    print('incorrect value')
if iterar <= 0:
    print('Please write a count of domains you want to be cheked')
i=0
while i<iterar:
    i=i+1
    allDomain = input(f'Enter Domain N{i}:')
    domainlist.append(allDomain)
while domainlist:
   domain = domainlist.pop(0)
   result = requests.get(f'http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=20&dat=snbamz&url={domain}')
   data_string = result.text
   root = et.fromstring(data_string) 
   rank = [item.attrib.get('RANK') for item in root.findall('.//REACH')]
   print(f"\nDomain: \'{domain}\'")
   print(f"Alexa Rank: {rank}\n".replace("[", "").replace("]", ''))
input()
```

Comment: Никак, потому что с многопоточностью Alexa забанит вас за DoS-атаку